# iOS GPS Arrow White or Purple Color What is the difference?

Tags: ios, colors, gps

The GPS arrow that appears in the status bar. For my app it always shows up as a white arrow even when the app is in the foreground. Whereas for the Maps app the arrow shows up as purple. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

purple means that it is actively using your location, whereas white means that it used the location services in the last 24 hours (but isnt currently requesting it)

Comment: I am actively requesting location and getting location updates. Still the arrow stays white. I even set the desiredAccuracy to kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and get updates every second. Still arrow stays white.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, they are just represented for different UI status style. 
Both of them are meaning that the GPS is running to get a latest location.

You should be able to set the status bar style at plist property: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque